# cURL not taking second argument in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below custom stage as part of one deployment. This works perfectly when i execute as pipeline script in a pipeline job.

However, when I put this in a shared library it is not taking the url & fails with url not found error.

```
 stage("Publish"){
     withCredentials([[$class:'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "credentials",
                 usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {

     def nexus_url = "https://myrepo.com/repository/kube-charts/charts/${env.APPNAME}/${env.PACKAGENM}"
     echo "url is ${nexus_url}"

     sh """
         cd ${env.APPNAME} ;
         curl -v -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} --upload-file index.yaml https://myrepo.com/repository/kube-charts/charts/${env.APPNAME}/index.yaml ;
         curl -v -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} --upload-file ${env.PACKAGENM}${nexus_url}
         """
     }
}
```

Also, the first curl works. Its the second curl where I have arguments, that fails with url not found error.

Error:

```
 + curl -v -u ****:**** --upload-file mypackage-1.3.tgz
   curl: no URL specified!
   curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: have you tried to log the URL? I've got the feeling that the given properties are not available from within the shared library.

Comment: Are you sure fisrt curl works? Its seems to me the error is related to the first because as you set verbose you dont have logs about it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between the ${env.PACKAGENM} and the ${nexus_url}.
Just add a space and it will work for you.